# Using eval to reference array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This sounds like a pretty simple one but I cannot use a "dynamic" variable to refer to an array. Say I wanted to pull up "Brent_Chart_1", to locate it in the array I would do something like this:

```
data[i].Brent_Chart_1
```

Suppose though I want to loop through a number of categories, and also wanted to pull up "WTI_Chart_1". I would want to do something like this:

```
$comm_array = array("Brent","WTI");

for(var comm; comm = comm_array.pop();){

...

data[i].eval(comm + "_Chart_1")

...

}
```

This, however, does not seem to work. How should I build this reference "dynamically"?

EDIT:

Here is further context on the issue:

```
if (data[i].ID == 39) {
    console.log(comm);
    $("#" + comm + "_Chart_1").highcharts('StockChart', jQuery.parseJSON(data[i][comm + '_Chart_1']));
} else {
    console.log(comm);
    $("#" + comm + "_Chart_1").highcharts(jQuery.parseJSON(data[i][comm + "_Chart_1"]));
}

comm + 1
}
```

Comment: [Don't use eval needlessly!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21)

Comment: You could use a while loop instead of a for loop in that instance, like `while(comm = comm_array.pop())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `data[i][comm + "_Chart_1"]` will work

Comment: data[i]["Brent_Chart_1"] works, but not data[i][comm + "_Chart_1"]

Comment: That is correct canon, and it did give me WTI first. The log returned the variables as expected ... namely Brent and WTI

Comment: The array is built properly, as data[i]["Brent_Chart_1"] works... but not data[i][comm + "Brent_Chart_1"]. We have also established that comm is ok as it appears fine in the console log

Comment: ALSO: I notice in the error log I get the following: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input "

Comment: canon, that was a typo, I meant [comm + "_Chart_1"]. I think the problem is that the code doesn't think comm is a sring. Is this because it has been pulled from an array?

Answer (score 4):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) like so:

```
data[i][comm + "_Chart_1"]
```